# Error: No module: ngRoute when trying to implement routing in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

```
app = angular.module("dithat", ["ngRoute", "ngResource", 'ng-rails-csrf']);
  app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'app/views/layouts/_user_page.html',
    controller: 'accomplishmentController'
  });
}]);
```

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have you included the `angular-route.js` file in your page? And are you using angular 1.2.0 - the module doesn't seem to exist prior to this.

See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: hi! no i didn't know that was required.  I just got the route.min.js from here http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/ and put it in my assets/javascripts file and put this <script src="/assets/angular-route.js"></script> in my application.html.erb but it gave me errors like TypeError: Cannot read property 'copy' of undefined angular-route.js:7
Error: Unknown provider: $sceProvider <- $sce <- $route <- ngViewDire

Comment: You need to tell it that it's JS.  So try:  <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/angular-route.js"></script>

Comment: What version of main angular.js file do you have?

Comment: im using this gem 'angularjs-rails'

Comment: In that case, it looks like you should be including `angular-route` with something like `//= require unstable/angular-route` in your gemfile. However, if you are not using unstable angular then I would expect @BKM is correct and you probably don't need the module.

Comment: Refer this page https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route to install ngRoute.

Answer (score 2):

Add `angular-route` into application.js like

in /app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require angular
//= require angular-resource
//= require angular-route
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove ngRoute from our dependency injection as you are already injecting routeProvider in config

```
app = angular.module("dithat", ["ngResource", 'ng-rails-csrf']);
  app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/', {
  templateUrl: 'app/views/layouts/_user_page.html',
  controller: 'accomplishmentController'
});
}]);
```