# Angularjs routing not working after upgrade from v1.0.8 --> v1.2.14

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've just upgraded my application from v1.0.8 --> v1.2.14 and now I'm not able to view any routes. I'm not sure how to debug this as the controller is not invoked either. I'm not getting any errors at all either?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks again

```
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/:a', {
            template: '<div data-ng-include="templateUrl">Loading...</div>',
            controller: 'DynamicController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/:a'
    });
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416575/error-no-module-ngroute-when-trying-to-implement-routing-in-angularjs

Comment: Hi There, I don't have an error at all. I've included the ng-route.js & added it as a dependency to the app. What else can I check? or how else can I debug it?

Comment: nothing wrong in the code you show. maybe in the rest of the code

Comment: hi There, I've put the code on my server. Thanks for your help. http://devseankerr.azurewebsites.net/tes/app/#/

Comment: At some point ngRoute was dropped from angular.js and offered as a separate module in angular-route.js. Do you have that script included as well? When you declare your module, are you listing ngRoute as a dependency?

Comment: is this your app? http://snag.gy/YL3S3.jpg

Comment: Hm, what is your problem actually? If I click on http://devseankerr.azurewebsites.net/tes/app/#/1 it seems to work without any problems.

Comment: Hi Guys, my bad. After working a massively long day I just missed something so obvious. @wayne & Adam you're both right there is nothing wrong at all. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not appending /#/a to my URL. The application was working fine.